# How to convert C# struct to C struct?

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 280), Serializable]
public struct AESContext
{
    /// int nr; 
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 4)]
    public int nr;

    /// unsigned long *rk;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
    public uint rk;

    // unsigned long buf[68];
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 68)]
    public uint[] buf;
}
```

This is C# struct I have so far. Comment above each field is type in C.
I would love if someone could verify.

Comment: Are you targeting Windows from C as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the C# struct for the C struct defined in the member contents.  If so then I believe you want the following

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
public struct AESContext
{
    /// int nr; 
    public int nr;

    /// unsigned long *rk;
    public UIntPtr rk;

    // unsigned long buf[68];
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 68)]
    public uint[] buf;
}
```

Basic changes

- Don't specify `SizeConst` in `StructLayout` unless you are trying to create a struct whose size is different (typically) bigger than it's contents.  It's not very common to do this
- `MarshalAs` isn't usually needed for primitive types
- Use `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr` to PInvoke pointer types.  They vary properly in size between 32 and 64 bit platforms